# adding to array for a specific user in firebase dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a course management app. and I'm trying to add a course to the list of courses

the process as that the instructor will create a course to himself then it should be added to the array he has as field.

for instance the instructor DR.Reema will add course MATH. ai should be saved in Courses List.

what im trying to achieve is to save course name in field courses which is an array for the current user. my problem is that i dont know how to get the current user to search for it in the list of instructors to add the course to his list

screenshots of our Firebase:

[image]

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final User? user = auth.currentUser;
  DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('list_instructors')
      .collection('Instructor')
      .doc(user!.uid);
ref.update({
    'Courses': FieldValue.arrayUnion([courseName, courseCode])
  });
```

Comment: Where is the "Courses" collection? Also can you please add shed some more light on your code.

Comment: We are going to need you to be more specific on what you are trying to achieve. Also please show us how does your Courses colleciton look like.

Comment: i want to save in a specific field in a document. the field courses in Dr Reema is a List. i want to save any new saved courses in that list

Comment: Can you upload a picture of how the Courses list of each instructor looks like?

Comment: i updated my post please take a look at it

Comment: @mightyleen Added an answer based on what I understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function like this should be useful to you as a good starting point:

```
void UpdateUser(String userName, String courseName){
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc('list_instructors')
    .collection('Instructor')
    .doc(userName)
    .update({'Courses': FieldValue.arrayUnion([courseName])})
    .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
}
```

You don't need to make sure that the course is already present in the array since if the `.update()` method detects there is already a Field with its name, it won't add a new one.

#### UPDATED ANSWER

Since you told me that you don't know the Instructor names, but only the email address, which is a field of those Instructor documents, something like this should work for you:

```
void UpdateUser(String email, String courseName){
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc('list_instructors')
    .collection('Instructor')
    .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        doc.reference.update({'Courses': FieldValue.arrayUnion([courseName])})
        .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"))
      })
    });
}
```

Comment: where is the value of userName coming from ? i dont know how to get the current user i only have his email when he logged in. how do i look for the user in the list of instructors with his email to add in the array?

Comment: Please post again what your Users collection look like.

Comment: done please check

Comment: @mightyleen Also, since emails can be used as unique ids, why don't you use those as your Instructor ids too?

Comment: my problem is in searching with email to add. i think one unique is enough